# Machine Precison for Roundoff

Tags: numerical-methods, machine-precision

Given the machine precision (machine epsilon) whose definition is that it is the smallest $\epsilon_{mach}$ such that 1 + $\epsilon_{mach}$ > 1. I found an explanation online to show that for **roundoff**, $\epsilon_{mach}$ is bounded above by $\frac{1}{2}\beta^{1-k}$ where $\beta$ is the base of the computer system and **k** is the length of the mantissa which is shown below. What I struggle to understand is the part where it says "**with borrowing during the subtraction, we get**" which is highlighted below in red. How does this step happen and what is the explanation behind it? And where do **$(\beta - d_{k+1})$** and **$(\beta - d_{k+2})$** come from?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The symbols $d_i$ and $e_i$ are not standardized (as far as I know)
and technically should be defined here.
(And they *were* apparently defined in the original text, if we can believe
the phrase "Using the above notation".)
But I guess that the digits $d_i$ are the digits of the infinite-precision representation of $x$, whereas $e_i$ are the digits of the finite-precision representation in which $x$ is stored in the computer,
and the exact value of that finite-precision representation is $fl(x).$

Under that interpretation, the phrase "borrowing during that subtraction"
may be meant to remind you that although $e_k = d_k + 1,$
the $k$th digit after subtraction is not $e_k - d_k = 1$ but $0.$
It is the same reason why $1200 - 1100 = 100$ but $1200 - 1110 = 90$;
in the first case we get a $1$ in the hundreds place because $2 - 1 = 1,$
but in the second case we do not get a $1$ in the hundreds place because we had to "borrow" it in order to deal with the fact that we had $10$ in the last two digits we were subtracting but only $00$ in the last two digits we were subtracting from.

But I find this entire explanation to be far more complicated than it needs to be. In my mind, the reason why $\lvert x - fl(x)\rvert \leq \frac12 \beta^{n-k}$
is simply that the next larger finite-precision number above $fl(x)$ is
$fl(x) + \beta^{n-k}$ and the next smaller finite-precision number below $fl(x)$
is $fl(x) - \beta^{n-k}$ (or in the special case where $fl(x)$ is exactly a power of $\beta$, the next smaller number is $fl(x) - \frac12 \beta^{n-k}$).

So (assuming positive $x$) you cannot have $x > fl(x) + \frac12 \beta^{n-k}$
because any number greater than $fl(x) + \frac12 \beta^{n-k}$
would have been rounded up to $fl(x) + \beta^{n-k}$ or to something even greater;
whereas any number less than $fl(x) - \frac12 \beta^{n-k}$
would have been rounded down to $fl(x) - \beta^{n-k}$
(or $fl(x) - \frac12 \beta^{n-k}$, if that is a finite-precision number)
or to something even less.
Therefore $fl(x) - \frac12 \beta^{n-k} \leq x \leq fl(x) + \frac12 \beta^{n-k},$
which is equivalent to
$$\lvert x - fl(x)\rvert \leq \frac12 \beta^{n-k}.$$
Similarly for negative $x$ any number that is outside the interval from
$fl(x) - \frac12 \beta^{n-k}$ to $fl(x) + \frac12 \beta^{n-k}$
would have been rounded up or down to a number different from $fl(x).$

Comment: But where do **$(\beta - d_{k+1})$** and **$(\beta - d_{k+2})$** in the highlighted part come from?

Comment: @VirgOpta : Like in decimal $1=0.999...$, so you get in basis $β$ that $1.0=[0.(β-1)(β-1)(β-1)(β-1)...]_β$. This then gives $1.000-[0.d_{k+1}d_{k+2}d_{k+3}...]_β=0.(β-1-d_{k+1})(β-1-d_{k+2})(β-1-d_{k+3})....]_β$ The complementary digits are wrong in the text. (A trailing $(β-1)$ digit sequence can then be compressed again if desired.)

Comment: @LutzLehmann I missed the errors in the complementary digits. All the more reason why one should avoid overly-complicated explanations, in my opinion.